# Exe binary crashes only outside IDE

Tags: c++, opencv

An OpenCV1.0 project uses the cvBlob structure a lot (functions parameters, lists of blobs, etc).

```
struct CvBlob{
    float   x,y,w,h;
    int     ID; }
```

I added some members with success inside the vc9 project, until I found out that the binary couldn't run outside the IDE in release mode. It crashes during a destruction somewhere (it doesn't when executed inside the project).

The new structure:

```
struct CvBlob{
    float   x,y,w,h;
    int     ID,myint; //Works fine.
    double* mydouble; //Crushes only outside visual studio.
}
```

During rutime, `mydouble` is used as an array:

```
blob.mydouble=new double [10];
```

Any generic advise, before I dive into the large source code?

**EDIT:** The debug runs successfully outside IDE.

**EDIT2:** The CvSeq is used as the main blob list container: `cvSeqPush(CvSeq*,CvBlob*)`, `cvSeqRemove(CvSeq*,int)`. Undefined behavior here?

Comment: Do you mean that a Debug build doesn't crash but a Release build does? (so, is it the IDE that's important or the type of build?)

Comment: @RogerRowland I edited the question. Yes, debug runs successfully outside IDE.

Comment: My guess would be that a debug build initialized all members to NULL while a release build doesn't and somewhere in your code you're checking for NULL before deallocating. You could try to initialize all pointers to NULL.

Comment: Do you use `delete [] mydouble` ?

Comment: @j.holetzeck No, not yet. I let OpenCV to handle the memory (e.g. CvSeq functionalities).

Comment: Is Visual Studio the IDE , and you're on Windows?

Comment: @RomanR. Visual studio 2008 with opencv 231 on winxp sp3.

Comment: to echo Krister Andersson: in my experience, this behavior is always caused by the use of uninitialized variables.  The use of improperly init'd pointers was mentioned, but also check things serving as loop bounds: array indices, stings indices, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you be able to extend the `CvBlob` structure and then add your own constructor and destructor to manage the memory for `myDouble`?

```
  struct MyCvBlob : CvBlob {
       double* myDouble;
       // initialize myDouble to NULL in constructor
       MyCvBlob() {
          myDouble = NULL;
       }
       // free the memory pointed to by myDouble if in use
       virtual ~MyCvBlob() {
          if(myDouble) {
             delete [] myDouble;
          }
       }
  };

  MyCvBlob blob;
  blob.myDouble = new double[10];
```

Answer (score 1):

> Any generic advise, before I dive into the large source code?

There is something wrong in your code, which give you eventually a trouble on runtime, but only under circumstances. Which might be not so obvious, e.g. different execution timings with and without debugger and consequent thread race conditions.

Something you still want to find out quick is the crash (esp. access violation) position. If Windows shows you a window indicating crashing process with an option to debug, you want to attach your debugger an possibly see a location of the problem. A crash itself might be not the first even in a chain of issues and it's already late to troubleshoot from there though.

Another approach is to attach a lightweight debugger, an overhead of which is smaller compared to full featured IDE debugger. For instance, you can attach [LogProcessExceptions](http://alax.info/blog/1211) application and have a minidump file written for every exception taking place on your application. Later on, the `.DMP` files can be opened retrospectively by Visual Studio, and the IDE will take you to source code positions at the time of exceptions.

Then another piece of generic advice is to produce some debug output and dissect your code into fragments to isolate the problem to specific small code fragment.

In particular, if you have a suspicion that destruction runs improperly, then perhaps you are trying to use deleted memory somewhere, and to troubleshoot the problem you might want to not release memory blocks extending their lifetime and creating a memory leak: specific block used after destruction earlier will be used correctly from there and your application will stop crashing. You will be able to find out what block the crash was related to.